# Spawning big amount of processes

Tags: simgrid

I want to spawn big amount of process. So I have `master` process which does it.

```
int master(int argc, char* argv[]){
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
        std::string name = std::to_string(i);
        MSG_process_create(name.c_str(), slave, NULL, MSG_host_self());
    }
    return 0;
    }

int slave(int argc, char* argv[]){
    XBT_INFO("%s", MSG_process_get_name(MSG_process_self()));
    return 0;
}
```

After I launch this program I have the following output:

```
....
....
[Master:32734:(32736) 0.000000] [master/INFO] 32734
[Master:32735:(32737) 0.000000] [master/INFO] 32735
[0.000000] /home/ken/Downloads/simgrid-master/src/simix/smx_context.cpp:187: [xbt/CRITICAL] Failed to protect stack: Cannot allocate memory

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Then I was advised to use `contexts/stack-size` parameter to change stack-size, because the previous program by default required 50000 * 8192 KiB.

I added this parameter `--cfg=contexts/stack-size:10` but I have the same output:

```
...
...
[Master:32735:(32737) 0.000000] [master/INFO] 32735
[0.000000] /home/ken/Downloads/simgrid-master/src/simix/smx_context.cpp:187: [xbt/CRITICAL] Failed to protect stack: Cannot allocate memory

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Or `--cfg=contexts/stack-size:100000`:

```
...
...
[Master:32734:(32736) 0.000000] [master/INFO] 32734
[0.000000] /home/ken/Downloads/simgrid-master/src/simix/smx_context.cpp:187: [xbt/CRITICAL] Failed to protect stack: Cannot allocate memory
```

It might seem that my program doesn't see this parameter, but it isn't the case because stack-parameter is `5` gives me:

```
Finally, if nothing of the above applies, this can result from a stack overflow.
Try to increase stack size with --cfg=contexts/stack_size (current size is 1 KiB).
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try maybe increasing the value of the maximum number of mappings allowed per process on your system ?

You can do that with sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=500000 to set the maximum value to 500000

We saw recently that this was causing some issues on some SMPI runs, maybe it's the same on your end. The "Cannot allocate memory" message may indeed be misleading, as the ENOMEM error code is set for various reasons (and according to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html, one of them may be the number of mappings).